# golang: How do you connect to multiple MySQL databases in Go?

Tags: mysql, go

operating 3 or more database at the same time,
Read/Write Splitting,
have connection pool.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? You can have multiple DB connections with multiple sql.Open calls. GoLang provides basic connection pool, and you can control it like so: http://go-database-sql.org/connection-pool.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just create different variables (db connections) using the Open function of sql library

```
import "database/sql"
import _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"

func Connect() (*DB, *DB, *DB) {
    db1, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user1:password1@/dbname1")
    //check err
    db2, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user2:password2@/dbname2")
    //check err
    db3, err := sql.Open("mysql", "user3:password3@/dbname3")
    //check err
    return db1, db2, db3
}
```

And you can use them further absolutely separately.